# Sencha Touch 2: make a checkbox transparent or hidden

Tags: css, extjs, checkbox, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to make my own checkbox by adding background-image to css styles:

```
.x-input-el + .x-field-mask {
    background-image:url(../images/checkbox-inactive.png);
}
```

and

```
.x-input-el:checked + .x-field-mask::after {
    background-image:url(../images/checkbox-active.png);
}
```

Everything goes pretty much OK, but I can't remove the native blue checkbox (although I'm able to change its color).
What's the proper way to remove the checkbox ?

Once I make font-size:0 or override something from app.css here:

```
.x-checkmark-base, .x-field-checkbox .x-field-mask::after, .x-field-radio .x-field-mask::after, .x-select-overlay .x-item-selected.x-list-item::after {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 10px;
bottom: 0;
content: '3';
font-family: 'Pictos';
font-size: 1.6em;
text-align: right;
line-height: 1.6em;
}
```

, I can't check the checkbox (it doesn't appear to be active upon check).
How to resolve this issue?
What should I do to hide the checkbox from the screen and keep all the rest as it has to be?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCyrillus, here is the the solution.

```
.x-checkmark-base, .x-field-checkbox .x-field-mask::after, .x-field-radio .x-field-mask::after, .x-select-overlay .x-item-selected.x-list-item::after {
    content:''
}
```

(some classes probably could be voided)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if you use checkbox + label, you may hide checkbox and style label.
Position:fixed + left:far away; might do it.

Give a test: http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/BFIno

```
label {
  display:inline-block;
  color:tomato
}
label:before {
  content:'✗';
  border:solid;
  border-radius:3px;
  padding: 0 0.15em;
}
input:checked + label {
  color:turquoise;
}
input:checked + label:before {
  content:'✓';
}
/* hide hecbox */
[type="checkbox"] {
  position:fixed;
  left:-9999px;
}
```

```
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ckckbx"/>
  <label for ="ckckbx"> lorem</label>
</p>
```

label or pseudo can hold your background-image.

Comment: Thank you, looks nice, but how to apply it to Sencha Touch 2?

Comment: do you mean how to add a xtype:label ?

Comment: Sorry. Is it still possible to apply some proper styles as far as modifying css styles is a preferable way without breaking or changing logic. Sorry for reasking. Thank you very much.

Comment: The css should do it, it's just that labels are missing "for" attributs as far I've understood in Sensa Touch. This is why a bit of javascript has to be added to have them reacting normal. If checkbox is translucide or hidden, you have no way to click it :)

Comment: The solution found. Please see my answer on my own question.

Comment: instead of a sign, give a size, eventually add a background almost translucide: rgba(0,0,0,0.01); This way it should remain clickable if no text around.